# applicationWillTerminate does not get invoked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to save my data before terminating, so my `AppControll` class conforms the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol, and declared the method; and in the interface builder I bound the window's delegate outlet to AppController, but I cannot get the method invoked.

Where I am wrong, what should I do?

Comment: @user408141: I notice (now) that @Firoze Lafeer added the [cocoa] and [osx] tags after the fact. Is that what you meant, or did you mean `UIApplicationDelegate` (Cocoa Touch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to add the handler to the application?

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
   name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];
```

Comment: The documentation suggests that this is not necessary: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate: Note that it's documented as taking the UIApplication object, not an NSNotification, which suggests that the delegate method is not a notification handler. You should not need to observe for the notification to receive this message. And even in Cocoa, where it is a notification, you still don't need to explicitly observe for it.

Comment: @Peter I don't quite get you. How can a method receive notifications without subscribing to / observing any event?

Comment: @William - because applicationWillTerminate: is part of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol, and will be invoked automatically by the system.  I'm with Peter, this should not be needed.

Comment: Wait a sec, the original question was talking about NSApplicationDelegate (not UIApplicationDelegate). How is this working?

Comment: @William: In UIKit, it isn't a notification method. (In AppKit, it is.) The UIApplication object sends that message to its delegate. Just being the delegate should be enough. (In AppKit, it is—I know for sure that you do not need to explicitly add the NSApplication's delegate as an observer; in AppKit, being the delegate *is* enough.)

Comment: @jenningj: I'd say that's in doubt. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 11):

Are you terminating the app from Xcode? Alternatively, is sudden termination enabled in your Info.plist?

Either of these will cause a `SIGTERM` signal to be sent to the application, terminating it immediately, with no chance for the NSApplication instance to send its delegate an `applicationWillTerminate:` message. (This is the point of sudden termination: Your app dies *instantly*. You can turn it off and on programmatically for times when this would be bad.)

Try quitting your application within itself (the Quit menu item in your Application menu), or using the Dock to quit it (right-click on your application's tile and choose “Quit”). As long as sudden termination is disabled (or never was enabled), either of these will cause your application object to send the `applicationWillTerminate:` message.

Also check that your delegate is getting sent other application-delegate messages, such as `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, and make sure you hooked up the outlet in the correct nib (your MainMenu nib).

Comment: This is false. `SIGKILL` terminates an application instantly. `SIGTERM` does give a program the chance to handle termination. (But I don't know how to catch sigterm in a macOS application, either.)

Comment: You'd need to use a signal handler. NSApplication theoretically could install one and catch `SIGTERM` to notify its delegate, but it doesn't (it only does that for the Quit Apple Event or the app's own Quit menu item). With no handler in place, `SIGTERM` terminates the process instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Is multitasking still enabled? That could be the problem - tapping the home button doesn't cause `applicationWillTerminate:` to be called if the app goes into the background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this question applies to macOS apps (as it mentions NSApplicationDelegate).

By default, Xcode 11 (and maybe earlier versions?) includes the [`NSSupportsSuddenTermination`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nssupportssuddentermination) property in new applications' `Info.plist` file:

```xml
  ...
  <key>NSSupportsSuddenTermination</key>
  <true/>
  ...
```

This property is associated with the `enableSuddenTermination` and `disableSuddenTermination` pair of methods in the [ProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo) (NSProcessInfo) class.

The relevant part of ProcessInfo documentation states:

> Sudden Termination
>
> macOS 10.6 and later includes a mechanism that allows the system to log out or shut down more quickly by, whenever possible, killing applications instead of requesting that they quit themselves.
>
> Your application can enable this capability on a global basis and then manually override its availability during actions that could cause data corruption or a poor user experience by allowing sudden termination. Alternately, your application can just manually enable and disable this functionality.

In other words, when `NSSupportsSuddenTermination` is true, when the user tries to quit the application (directly or indirectly), macOS terminates it, instead of requesting it to quit. This bypasses any events that would otherwise be triggered during a regular quit request.

The good new is that you can either disable that in the `Info.plist` file, or manually override it, according to your application's needs, by calling `ProcessInfo.processInfo.disableSuddenTermination()`.

Answer (score 0):

In `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
    name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: copies existing answer above

Comment: @MaxMacLeod No reason for a downvote. Votes are supposed to tell the reader the quality of an answer and the user who seeks for help doesn't case if there is another answer with the same content or not. This answer is good and this answer is right and just because someone else was faster doesn't make this a bad answer. If duplication was a problem, it would be possible to flag posts as duplicate but as you can see, there is no duplicate flag.

Comment: @Mecki you have some good points. Although in this case the duplicate answer was posted five years later. 

I'm happy to improve my SO behaviour. Could you reference any SO help links that back up your comment?

Comment: @MaxMacLeod E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down doesn't mention that you should down vote duplicate answers and you should also not downvote duplicate questions  - rather flag them. And not even duplicate questions are such a big problem http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ As all answers are CC license, you are even explicitly allowed to re-use content of another answer in your own answer. If the answer was an exact, verbatim, one to one duplicate... but it isn't and great minds think alike ;-)