# Contents of NSArray saved in NSUserDefaults gets overwritten whenever the view controller is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, singleton, nsuserdefaults

A View Controller contains:

1. **UITextField**(Name).
2. **UIButton**(save).

Once I type any name and hit save, The name is added to an array which is stored using `NSUserDefaults`.

This View Controller is pushed from another View Controller and so when I go and come back to this View Controller, the contents of `NSArray` gets overwritten with the new names that i might specify. I'm not sure whats causing this but i'm suspecting that it has to do something with `allocation` and `initialization` of `NSArray`.

In my ViewDidLoad, I did `NSMutableArray *namesList= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

And in my `OnSave` method,

```
[namesList addObject:nameTextField.text];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:namesList forKey:@"namesListArray"];
NSLog(@"items in array: %@",namesArray);
```

EDIT:
Screenshot of related View Controllers:

[image]

Here, when i click the `ADD` button, the second View Controller is pushed.
When i enter "kenneth" and hit save, the console says:

```
2014-03-03 11:03:46.219 SmartWatch[664:a0b] items in array: (
kenneth)
```

Now, without going back to the previous View Controller ,when i type another name say,"john" and hit save, the console says:

```
2014-03-03 11:15:43.646 SmartWatch[664:a0b] items in array: (
kenneth,
john)
```

Until now everything is good.
The problem occurs when i go back to the previous Controller and come back to the second View Controller.Now, when i type another name ,say "scott",the console says:

```
2014-03-03 11:19:50.815 SmartWatch[664:a0b] items in array: (
scott)
```

This means that the previous two names were overwritten. I want the array to retain "kenneth" and "john" too and "scott" should actually be appended to the array.

I think this happens because the array gets initialized when the second View Controller comes to the foreground again but I'm not sure of it and i dont know how to rectify this.

Hope the question is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: You want that your old values to be retained?

Comment: yes, i want my old values to be retained  @rajesh

Comment: Then allocating array every time will erase previous data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *nameArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"namesListArray"];
NSMutableArray * namesList;
if (!nameArray) {
    namesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else {
    namesList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nameArray];

}
```

On save

```
[namesList addObject:nameTextField.text];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: namesList forKey:@"namesListArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `nameList` array as a property and in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.namesList = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"namesListArray"] mutableCopy];


 if (nil == namesList) 
    {
        self.namesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
```

`onSave` method

```
[self.namesList addObject:nameTextField.text];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.namesList forKey:@"namesListArray"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are doing any functionality to store elements to nsarray in **ViewWillAppear** Method.
If not please specify your code properly to help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` at end of  [`NSUserDefaults.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method) Other wise problem is else where, you need to to put relevant code with output of `NSUserDefaults`.