# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark stay on tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am aware that on row selection you can have a check mark appear by using the following code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

How do I get the check mark to stay on the selected rows if the user is too move between different view controllers?

Thanks

Comment: You have to store index path of specific cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UITableViewController` set [`clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear) to `NO`.

If you want the selection preserved after the table view controller has been deallocated you'll need to store the selected items somewhere like `NSUserDefaults`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSArray *previousSelection = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"selection"];
    for (NSArray *selection in previousSelection) {
         [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selection[1] inSection:selection[0]] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    NSArray *selections = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    NSMutableArray *selectionsToSave = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSIndexPath *selection in selections) {
        [selectionsToSave addObject:@[selection.section, selection.row]];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:selectionsToSave forKey:@"selection"];
    // Save as iOS 7 now saves less frequently - see note
    [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Note on the use of [`synchronize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method/9647965#9647965)

EDIT:
Corrected answer thanks to @rmaddy pointing out that you can only put simple types in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: This won't work. You can't store `NSIndexPath` objects in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @rmaddy that should be better! Thanks for spotting that :)

Comment: That should work but personally I would never do this. It would be better to store some sort of key for each selected row in case the order or number of rows ever change.

Comment: Yeah, you'd be better off using core data to back the data, but the OP hasn't given much info...!