# How do I store the High Score?

Tags: ios, swift

How would I store the high score. When I exit out of the app the high score goes back to 0. This is the code which will determine the high score.

```
if(scoring.text > best.text){
    best.text = String(score)
}
```

Comment: sorry about that, just edited the post

Comment: [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults. See Code Below...

**Save The Score**

```
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        defaults.setObject(self.scorelabel.text, forKey: "Score")


        defaults.synchronize()
```

**Load The Score Back**

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if let scoreIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("Score") as? String {
            self.scorelabel.text = defaults.objectForKey("Score") as String


        }
```

Comment: Don't use syncronize, it's badddddddd

Comment: May I ask why @adminXVII?

Comment: Why did you say synchronize was bad. Its not bad!

Comment: Don't think so either. @nachshonfertel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647965/4950659

Comment: Ok, but is there any *disadvantage* using `synchronize()`?

Comment: @LinusG. Did you read the whole post he linked?  "In fact, it's a performance problem if you call `synchronize` every time you set a default."

Comment: Oh right, must have missed that. Thanks @NobodyNada

Answer (score 2):

The option I recommend you to use is `NSUserDefaults`. You can store an int like that:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "HighScore")
```

and retrieve it like that:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighScore")
```

Comment: He asked for Swift code as he posted Swift code so make sure to always answer using the appropriate language.

Comment: @LinusG. You're right, didn't realized it... Should I delete my post or should I keep it for programmers who use Obj-C ?

Comment: It's ok. I would suggest leaving it and adding a note that it is for Objective-C or / and adding Swift code if you can.

Comment: @adminXVII You could edit it.  If you don't know Swift, I could edit it for you.

Comment: @NobodyNada I would be really grateful if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to save data:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults?.setObject(score, forKey: "HighScore")
defaults?.synchronize()
```

You can read it the following way:

```
let x = defaults.valueForKey("HighScore") as! Int //or String, depending on what you need
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store the high score.