# NSUserDefaults category not saving in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I have made a category for saving number of app runs like so,

```
static NSString * const AppRuns = @"IP_AppRuns";

@implementation NSUserDefaults (RegisteredUser)

+ (void)saveRuns:(NSNumber *)value
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:AppRuns];
}

+ (NSNumber *)runs
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AppRuns];
}
....
```

And I'm setting it in my App delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[NSUserDefaults saveRuns: @(21)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"App has run %ld times", [[NSUserDefaults runs] integerValue]);
```

But, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, which makes me suspect that it isn't getting saved.

However, the following works:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(17) forKey:@"AppRuns"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"App has run %ld times", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"AppRuns"] integerValue]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried the top one and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Try setting an exception breakpoint to make sure you know where the exception is occuring, or posting a backtrace

Comment: @WillM. Did you try by creating a category? And calling the method from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? I will try setting a breakpoint.

Comment: Yup. I created a category for `NSUserDefaults`, copied your code into it, filled in the header, imported that header into `AppDelegate` and then copied your calling code into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Got this output `2015-07-31 14:11:57.674 TestStuff[52594:6855419] App has run 21 times`

Comment: also note that you don't need to call synchronize so often http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method

Comment: Thanks for confirming the category code isn't the problem @WillM.. 
I thought this was related to old keys as Klevison suggested and tried the removeObjectForKey, still no avail. I'm simply using the second method I wrote above.

Comment: Did you set the exception breakpoint to try to find the line it was crashing on? Do this by going to the breakpoint menu in the left menu (looks like a pentagon thing, second from the right), then click the plus at the bottom left of the screen, then "Add exception breakpoint"

Answer (score 0):

`+ (NSNumber *)runs` uses `objectForKey` to access `NSUserDefaults`

Your second example uses `valueForKey` to access `NSUserDefaults`

`valueForKey` and `objectForKey` both will return the object for the given key. But here `valuForKey` is key-value coding (KVC).

If key does not start with “@”, invokes `objectForKey:`. If key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes `[super valueForKey:]` with the rest of the key.

**EDITED**

Can you reinstall your app(clean old `NSUserDefaults` values) and try this code?

```
@implementation NSUserDefaults (RegisteredUser)

+ (void)saveRuns:
{
    NSNumber *runs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AppRuns];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:runs++ forKey:@"Runs"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

+ (NSNumber *)runs
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Runs"];
}
```

Comment: I changed `objectForKey` in the category methods with `valueForKey`, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you got problem with old values.. My answer was edited.. try it

Comment: Still getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. :( Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) Check if existe value for `objectForKey`..  If not you cant sum this value (runs++).. 2) add an exception breakpoint and see the line error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/846780