# Why my highscore stopped updating?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, scoring

I've made a highscore and tested it several hours ago, it worked fine. My best score was 6 and game saved it. But now, I've made a score of 10, then 12 and it still shows me that my highscore is 6. I'm pretty sure I did not touch anything related to that piece of code after I've made it.
 Here is my highscore:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
//highscore
var HighScoreDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

if (score > HighScoreDefaults) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
var showHighscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

highScoreText.text = "Highscore : \(showHighscore)"
highScoreText.fontSize = 34
highScoreText.fontColor = SKColor.grayColor()

}
```

What could go wrong?

**EDIT:** So I put my code, edited by @trojanfoe in `override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)` function and it's working again. I honestly don't know what caused that problem, but for those who have same problem that I had – try Update instead of `didMoveToView`.

Comment: nothing wrong with the code

Comment: trust user defaults and don't read the value immediately after writing it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work, however there have been changes to *when* `NSUserDefaults synchronize` actually writes the data to disk (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method)).

Given you know what the new highscore is, you can avoid the issue entirely by using this (slightly more efficient and more obvious) code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //highscore
    var highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    if (score > highScore) {
        highScore = score;
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    highScoreText.text = "Highscore : \(highScore)"
    highScoreText.fontSize = 34
    highScoreText.fontColor = SKColor.grayColor()
}
```

(i.e. avoiding the additional reading of `NSUserDefaults`).

Comment: I tried your code now, but unfortunately it's not working for me. I've made a score of 7 and it still shows me 6 :(

Comment: @Burundanga Are you sure that `score > 6`?  (Use the debugger to check).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to use a debugger to check that. All I know that my score label was 7. I'll try to make a bigger score in an hour

Comment: So yeah, it's not working. Could something other possibly be a problem?