# Sessions in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, session

If I have a logged in user and stored his id inside the app using

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

How can make it as a session so I can use it in every page

example Welcome "userLoggedin"

Comment: Don't use `synchronize` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647965/2227743).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you store the id user, you use:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userId, forKey:"userId");
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

In other page:

```
let userId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userId") as? [String]
```

Answer (score 5):

use singleton maybe helpful:

```
class LoginInfo {

var isLogin:Bool = false
static let shareInstance = LoginInfo()

init() {}
}

// when login success set isLogin be true
LoginInfo.shareInstance.isLogin = true

// when login out set isLogin be false
LoginInfo.shareInstance.isLogin = false

// in other pages can call this
if LoginInfo.shareInstance.isLogin {
        // do something
}
```

hope it be helpful :-)