# how to remove an object inside an NSMutableDictionary which is inside a NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to remove an object from a dictionary which is in userdefaults.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userDefaults = (NSMutableDictionary*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
[userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"XYZ"];
```

The above code removes the whole dictionary.

XYZ is a `NSMutuableDictionary`. I want to remove an object with key "Password" from XYZ.

Comment: Can u show me the userDefault values here?

Comment: userDefaults contains three nsmutable dictionary.

Comment: ok.. So do u want to clear the one of the three dictionaries or simply a object with key "XYZ" in one of the dictionaries?

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal
 jus a object with key in one of the dictionaries

Comment: Do you want to remove that key value from dictionary only or want to remove it from NSUserDefaults too? if want to remove it from nsuserdefaults too, then you have to resync it again

Comment: @MehulThakkar, jus from the dictionary.

Comment: @Amon, see my answer below which has explanations on how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[defaults objectForKey:@"XYZ"] mutableCopy];
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"Password"];
[defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"XYZ"];
```

Comment: i tried this.but am getting an error "mutating method send to inmutable object"

Comment: NSUserDefaults will return an immutable NSDictionary, make a mutable copy of it. `[[defaults objectForKey:@"XYZ"] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
// Access the dictionary you want to edit as a mutable copy
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dictKey"] mutableCopy];

// Remove the object for the key
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"keyToRemove"];

// Set the dictionary back in user defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"dictKey"];

// Save your changes:
// If you need
// In applicationDidEnterBackground: in iOS >= 7.0
// If you are using iOS < 7.0
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: you don't need to synchronize. As of iOS 7 you don't need to call it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method

Comment: "As of iOS 7 that is no longer the case so you might want to call synchronize in your app delegate's applicationDidEnterBackground: or register to the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification to do that." --- It doesn't always call it when you want, so there's really no harm in using it (as long as you don't call it every time you are setting NSUserDefaults).

Comment: You just quoted/stated exactly what I was saying...Thank you? Why wouldn't you just call it one time when the app enters the background to avoid any performance issues. "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."

Comment: Oh I see what you are refusing to understand, let me update my answer