# how to store the integer value to the NSUserdefaults in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

```
int ramdomnumber = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ramdomnumber forKey:@"contactno"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

i tried the above code but it showing the error like **implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id_nullable' is disallowed with ARC**.can anyone suggest me how to store the int value in the nsuserdefaults .

Comment: int ramdomnumber = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(ramdomnumber) forKey:@"contactno"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use NSNumber to store the integer values for example,

```
int ramdomnumber = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
 NSNumber *randomNo = [NSNumber numberWithInt: ramdomnumber]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: randomNo forKey:@"contactno"]; //save NSNumber instance not the int 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to get integer back, same way,

```
NSNumber *savedNo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"contactno"];
int ramdomnumber = savedNo.intValue;//[savedNo intValue];
```

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs because you are passing a **scalar** type to a method which expects an **object**.

There is a dedicated method, it's good programming habit to cast the value to the expected type;

```
NSInteger ramdomnumber = (NSInteger)(arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ramdomnumber forKey:@"contactno"];
// [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

`synchronize` is not needed.

Comment: thank u very much sir ,i got it

Comment: [I think synchronize is needed...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647965/1066828) & better to be used for safe-side

Comment: @FahimParkar Did you read also the answer quoting the documentation? It reveals it's only needed in a few rare cases.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that int is not an Object, what you should do is:

```
int ramdomnumber = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ramdomnumber] forKey:@"contactno"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```