# Persisting data in iOS app

Tags: ios, userdefaults

I am new to iOS. I want to save `authentication token` recieved from a `REST API` to use in further api calls without requiring a login. Currently I am using `UserDefaults` to store this token. This token works fine unless app is completely closed. Relaunching the app again takes me to login screen.

Saving the `token` like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(authToken, forKey: "auth_token")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() // Now this call is derpecated. Framework handles this call at proper places.
```

**LoginViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_token") != nil { 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login_success", sender: self)
   }
}
```

But the issue is how can I persist this token even after the app was completely closed ?

**EDIT**

I have also tried syncing `UserDefaults` within `applicationWillTerminate` methods of `AppDelegate` class just to make sure but that even doesn't work.

Comment: app close meant killing the app ?

Comment: yes, killing the app

Comment: @NaumanZafar Could you Please show your userdefult data store code ?

Comment: @DixitAkabari updated.

Comment: @NaumanZafar i will check its working fine for me. i also don't set UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() then its work fine.

Comment: @DixitAkabari check the synchorinizer() method functionality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method

Comment: @isamankumara, now the framework calls this method automatically at right time. and will be deprecated in future releases. So it is recommended to remove any calls to synchronize.

Comment: @isamankumara after iOS 7 its deprecated its manage automatically.

Comment: yes you are correct. @DixitAkabari

Comment: @DixitAkabari, Please check I have answered this question. Wrapping the `performSegue` call in main dispatch queue solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the UserDefaults. Just wrapping the triggering segue call in main queue was required to properly work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_token") != nil {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login_success", sender: self)
       }
     }          
}
```