# iOS Application Does Not Run In Background = YES - how do I check when the user exits app

Tags: ios, appdelegate

In my info.plist file I have  Application Does Not Run In Background = YES. This is an enterprise app and I am trying to log when a user exits (hits the home button). But in AppDelegate, I was logging to the console to see what method would be called and none of them were (applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillTerminate). Is there a way to determine when a user exits with the plist setting I have>?

Thanks

Here's the willTerminate method, it's right out of the box:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"goodbye");
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.



}
```

I've changed the plist settings and can now log from applicationDidEnterBackground.

Comment: possible duplicate of [applicationWillTerminate when is it called and when not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818045/applicationwillterminate-when-is-it-called-and-when-not)

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want the app to run in the background but you want to know when the app terminates? Do this

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                                            object:app];
```

Then fill in your own applicationWillTerminate method. You won't have much time to do stuff.

Comment: There is no need for this. The app delegate already has its applicationWillTerminate method that is called in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set ApplicationDoesNotRunInBackgound to YES, then this must work,

put this method in your appDelegate.m

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"user exits app");
}
```

In my app, with the same plist settings, this method fires

Comment: willTerminate was in there but nothing will log.

Comment: could you please post your willTerminate method here..?? Is that in the AppDeleate.m file ?