# The applicationWillTerminate method is called always

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in the middle of development of an iOS OpenGL based game. So far I was not very concerned with the app states change and life cycle - background, foreground, suspended, terminated etc. Now I wanted to add support to moving the app into a suspended mode (after pressing home) and then nicely recuperate it after restarting it.

My problem is that after pressing home button, the app always gets terminated (the application delegate always reaches `-applicationWillTerminate:`)

The documentation mentions that in order to prevent termination it is important to clear as much memory as possible, stop any timers etc. Doing this did not help to prevent termination, so I tried to experimentally copy the app delegate form an Xcode template app, with completely NO initialization of my app objects after launch/activation, no storyboard, nothing special in main.m.

While the template (I used an Xcode game template) is never terminated after pressing home, it ends at `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`, my app despite of the fact that is uses less memory and starts completely no tasks is always terminated.

What may be the reason. Included but inactive frameworks ? I have no clue.

Comment: Did you set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend=YES in your Info.plist?  Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818045/applicationwillterminate-when-is-it-called-and-when-not.

Comment: Also, do you hear any memory warnings before the application terminates?

Comment: @Martin R - exactly - UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend was set to YES. Changing it to NO solves the problem. Many thanks.